# Scanning for a Specific Bluetooth Device on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3285580/620197) about scanning for Bluetooth device, which pretty much mirrors the Android docs, but I find that is good when the phone (or tablet) has not previously been paired with another (in my case a Point of Sale terminal).

However, after pairing has occurred, and relevant data about the POS stored (name and address), how would I go about establishing a connection directly to the POS (or another device where the name and address is known) without going through the discovering process again?  I find the Android docs a bit lacking in this aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the getRemoteDevice(String address) on the BluetoothAdaptor to get the BluetoothDevice Object for the remote device specified in address.

Then you can connect to that device using

```
public BluetoothSocket createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord (UUID uuid)
```

Comment: I can't find the "getBluetoothDevice(String address)" method in the Android docs

Comment: Found it the method name is "getRemoteDvice(Stirng address)"