# Continuously Scan Bluetooth Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've written the below code to continuously scan Bluetooth devices based on the solution provided in the [*link*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285580/how-to-periodically-scan-for-bluetooth-devices-on-android). According to the solution, my device should continuously scan/search Bluetooth devices in range, but in my case scan happens only for ~64 seconds.

I've tested this code on two devices, one with Android V2.2 and the other with V2.3, both the devices scan only for ~64sec.

How do I make my device scan continuously?

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){

          //Do Something

        }else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
            btAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Veer How did you accomplish the task of continuous bluetooth scan?

Comment: @Ameya Phadke Do you have any idea of making bluetooth scan continuous?