# How to scan all bluetooth devices every second (or less)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to scan for Bluetooth devices using the Bluetooth discovery method. At the moment I have implemented something similar to the following (top answer): [How to periodically scan for bluetooth devices on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285580/how-to-periodically-scan-for-bluetooth-devices-on-android)

However, as mentioned in the top answer this only scans every 12 seconds where I need this scan time to be reduced down to < 1s~. Can't seem to find much useful information online.

The Bluetooth modules I'm scanning for do support BLE, if that helps.

Comment: 12 seconds is a default scanning interval and could be stopped by the cancelDiscovery(), so call this function after 1s of scanning

Comment: @vookimedlo That seems to work, thanks :)

Comment: Posted as answer so this question could be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12 seconds is a default scanning interval and could be stopped by the cancelDiscovery(), so call this function after 1s of scanning.